# WPF Path Geometry Style in different colors

Tags: c#, wpf, button, geometry, controltemplate

I use a Path Geometry Group to build a geometry that replaces a Button in WPF:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="bT" TargetType="Button">

        <Path StrokeThickness="1.5" >
            <Path.Data>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="7,7" RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7" />
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="4,4" EndPoint="10,10" />
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="10,4" EndPoint="4,10" />
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>

            <Path.Style>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="LightGray" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Path.Style>

        </Path>
    </ControlTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

The Button is implemented like

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=bT}" />
```

Now my problem is that i can not style my geometries in different colors. For example i want a diffrent behaviour for my EllipseGeometry than for my LineGeometries.
Is there a way to to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have several named Paths in your ControlTemplate, move the `IsMouseOver` Trigger to `ControlTemplate.Triggers` and use `TargetName` in the Setters. Note also that there is a default Style for all Paths in the ControlTemplate.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="bT">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="LightGray"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1.5"/>
        </Style>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>

    <Canvas>
        <Path x:Name="circle">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="7,7" RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path x:Name="cross">
            <Path.Data>
                <GeometryGroup>
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="4,4" EndPoint="10,10"/>
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="10,4" EndPoint="4,10"/>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="circle" Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter TargetName="cross" Property="Stroke" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The `cross` Path could also be written shorter by using [Path Markup Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax):

```
<Path x:Name="cross" Data="M4,4 L10,10 M4,10 L10,4"/>
```

Comment: This looks very nice to me. But there are still two open points for me:
the free space between cross and circle is not clickable. is there a smarter solution than putting any transparent geometry in it?

also i dont understand your shorter code snipped for the cross. how do i read "M4,4 L10,10 M4,10 L10,4"?

Comment: For the first point, there is `<Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>` in the default Path Style. The default Fill is null, which means that it isn't hit-test visible. You may also set a transparent `Background` on the Canvas, to make the whole button area hit-test visible. For the second point, see [Path Markup Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax).

Comment: Great, everything is running very well. Thank you very much!